# Summing values in the same column based on conditions

Tags: dataframe, percentage

I have a data frame "Country" which looks like this:

```
Country
1
2
1
3
4
5
4
2
2
3
4
4
3
4
5
```

I calculate the percentages of each of the values in the column using the code below:

```
percent = df_test['Country'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
```

The code above gives me the individual percentages of the values 1 until 5.

However, I would like to calculate the summed percentages for 1 and 3 together. The remaining values should be separately summed together.

Any leads on how this could be done are appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: why not sum the percentage you got for 1 and 3, and get the total percentage for the two? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes that can be done. But the actual dataset contains more that 100 such rows so I was wishing if that can be done using code.

Comment: Are they all 1 up to 5?

Comment: In the entire dataset, they are many, not only 1 until 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So how come this doesn't work? @Jishan

```
ratio_1 = df_test['Country'].value_counts(normalize=True)['1']
ratio_3 = df_test['Country'].value_counts(normalize=True)['3']
percent_1_3 = (ratio_1 + ratio_3)*100
```

Comment: I edited the column a bit in the question. The first column did not explain my dataset properly. Will iloc also work in this case?
And there are different datasets with the same column. They all have different locations of 1-5.

Comment: @Jishan I've edited my answer, it should work however the data structure is

Comment: @Jishan Hopefully 1,2,3 ... are integers in your dataset and not strings like '1', '2', '3', ... Add quotation mark if they're strings

Comment: Oh, they are actually strings and not integers.

Comment: Then wrap them in a single quote in your ansewr